# Android separate EditText text into multiple TextViews

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have a EditText which contains a date e.g. 15/05/2016 and I want a TextView to contain only a small part of the information contained within the EditText e.g. the EditText displays 15/05/2016 and my TextView looks at it and takes the number 15 from the date and displays it within its TextView.

I'm asking this purely out of interest to see if its possible and if so does anyone have any examples of this method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
String date = editText.getText().toString(); // date = 15/05/2016
String[] dateParts = date.split("/");
textView.setText(dateParts[0]); // textView is 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are asking for is possible. You can do this by first saving the EditText value to a String, then analyzing it. After that you can display it in your TextView. Here is an example:

```
String date = editText.getText();
String[] vals = date.split("/");
textView1.setText(vals[0]);
textView2.setText(vals[1]);
textView3.setText(vals[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
String[] dateSplit = yourEditText.getText().toString().split("/");
textView.setText(dateSplit [0]);
```